# R lidR include filename of LAS object tile in interactive map popup

Tags: r, lidr

Is it possible to show the `filename` of the tile selected in the interactive `leaflet` plot?

Currently it's empty as shown below. However, whenever I expand the object in the Environment pane, I can see that the filenames along with the entire file path are indeed stored in the LAS catalog object.

Purpose: Sometimes an ROI polygon spans over multiple tiles (which may reside in different folders). So, If I can know the filenames of the tiles covering the `ROI`, I can copy those tiles in a folder and retile them and clip the `ROI` that way.

Code:

```
library(lidR)

    # Plot individual LAS objects
    plot(FL_LAS_List, mapview = TRUE,
         map.type = "OpenStreetMap")
```

Current output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually displayed. The problem is that the CRS being a WKT string it is absurdly long and all features are aligned on the right. You actually see nothing. You can maybe delete the CRS with `FL_LAS_List$CRS <- ""`

> Sometimes an ROI polygon spans over multiple tiles (which may reside in different folders)

As I already told you in previous questions it is not a problem. You can bind the collections into one and perform your queries seamlessly.

Comment: Cool so, using `rbind` to merge multiple LAS catalog objects into a single LAS catalog object (like you mentioned in the other answer), this new object can then be used to clip ROI a polygon spanning over different tiles?

Comment: As long as the binded object looks ok and consistent (same CRS, continuous set of tile, no duplicated tiles and so on), yes. Even if you have duplicated tile actually it will work but it will load some points twice.